# AWS Lambda & AWSGI

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda, wsgi

I have an AWS Lambda function which uses 'import awsgi'. I have uploaded the **aws-wsgi** & **awsgi** python dependencies, with other dependencies, to an S3 bucket. Then, uploaded all the dependencies to a Lambda Layer, connecting it with the aforementioned S3 bucket.

However, when I try to run the function, I get the following error:

```
{  
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'awsgi'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "81e04845-856a-4b98-85a4-7de4644e6244",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

I first tried only with **aws-wsgi** **library** (https://github.com/slank/awsgi) but then added the **awsgi** dependency to the zipped file too. But still getting the same error.
To make sure that the issues in my local environment didn't interrupt, I installed the dependencies in a virtual environment.

Comment: were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes. What is was doing wrong was that I was packaging the dependencies into a folder named dependency instead of python.